# Find IP blocks for a hosting provider

Tags: ip, hosting, web-hosting

Is there anyway to pick a hosting provider and get all IP addresses which they have assigned to them? I've tried the RIPE database but a) it only returns 250 results and b) it includes entries which aren't necessarily applicable. I just wondered if there is a simple way of finding out.

Comment: Why not just ask them?

Comment: I have - just wondered if there was an easier way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [RADb](http://www.radb.net/) as a tool to do this.

First, you will need to find the provider's autonomous system number (AS number). To do this, first find *any* IP address for the provider. For this example I will use well known provider Hetzner.

```
$ host www.hetzner.de
www.hetzner.de has address 78.46.133.14
www.hetzner.de has IPv6 address 2a01:4f8:d0a:2001::3
```

Then look up that IP address at RADb:

```
$ whois -h whois.radb.net 78.46.133.14 | grep ^origin
origin:         AS24940
```

Here, you should double check that the AS number actually belongs to Hetzner. Many small hosting providers do not have their own AS and are simply customers of a larger network. You should also do this check if the above returns two or more AS numbers (which should never happen, but I have seen it once).

```
$ whois as24940 | grep ^descr
descr:          Hetzner Online GmbH
```

So we see their ASN really is AS24940. Now, we do a [much more complex query](http://www.radb.net/support/query1.php) at RADb to get all of the known routes for that ASN.

```
$ whois -h whois.radb.net -- -i origin -T route AS24940 | grep ^route
route:          213.133.96.0/19
route:          213.239.192.0/18
route:          193.28.90.0/24
route:          193.110.6.0/23
route:          85.10.192.0/18
route:          193.223.77.0/24
route:          88.198.0.0/16
route:          78.46.0.0/15
route:          188.40.0.0/16
route:          178.63.0.0/16
route:          46.4.0.0/16
route:          91.220.49.0/24
route:           176.9.0.0/16
route:           194.42.180.0/22
route:           194.42.184.0/22
route:           176.102.168.0/21
route:           5.9.0.0/16
route:           194.145.226.0/24
route:          185.12.64.0/22
route:           144.76.0.0/16
route:          148.251.0.0/16
route:          136.243.0.0/16
route:          138.201.0.0/16
route:          193.25.170.0/23
route:          91.233.8.0/22
route:          185.50.120.0/23
route:          213.169.144.0/22
route:          197.242.84.0/22
route:          195.248.224.0/24

$ whois -h whois.radb.net -- -i origin -T route6 AS24940 | grep ^route
route6:          2a01:04f8::/29
```

Aggregating these is left as an exercise to the reader.

Note that these examples use GNU jwhois, which is commonly distributed with Linux systems. If you have a different whois client, you may need to adjust the command lines accordingly.

Comment: I don't think you would do it in Windows at all (which is true of many things). And the website search is really for casual use, not anything serious like this. Your CentOS machine has jwhois as its default whois and is a fine platform for work such as this.

Comment: There is a windows version which has fixed my problem fully. Thanks.